# ssl handshake on every request in multiThreaded client

Tags: java, multithreading, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

Architecture is midTier Liberty server that receives http requests and brokers to various back ends, some REST, some just JSON.  When I configure for SSL (only thru envVars which is quite cool) ... it appears I get a full handShake w/every request.  Additionally, the server side uses a different thread with each request (may be related). This is Liberty so it is multiThreaded.  Servlet has static ref to POJO that does all apache httpClient work.  Not using HttpClientContext (in this case).  Basic flow is at end (struggling w/formatting for post legality)

EnvVars are:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/root/lWasServers/certs/zosConnKey.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/root/lWasServers/certs/zosConnTrust.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=fredpwd
-Dhttp.maxConnections=40
```

Looked at many similar problems, but again, right now this flow does not use client context.  Hoping I'm missing something simple.  Code being appended on first response as I continue to struggle here w/FF in RHEL.

```
private static PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = null ;
private static CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null ;
// ....
cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
cm.setMaxTotal(512);
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(256) ;
httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm).build() ;
// ...
responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
```

Comment: Does the server require or want client authentication?

Comment: Thanks for response.  The answer is yes ... the midTier is another server, and in this prototype, the midTier is trusted, and thus thee is a need for client certificates.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If a persistent HTTP connection is stateful and is associated with a particular security context or identity, such as SSL key or NTLM user name, HttpClient tries to make sure this connection cannot be accidentally re-used within a different security context or by a different user. Usually the most straight-forward way of letting HttpClient know that requests are logically related and belong to the same session is by executing those requests with the same HttpContext instance. See [HttpClient tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/advanced.html#stateful_conn) for details. One can also disable connection state tracking if HttpClient can only be accessed by a single user or within the same security context. Use with caution.

Comment: I think this may tie back to setting up the HttpClientContext (in that my code is threadSafe, I need to figure out the scope of that context ... it may be that I just need to play with this a bit.  It is a trusted midTier ... I probably just need to get my head around how many contexts and reUse of same.

Comment: So a question ... since I don't control the threading (I'm a thread in a server) ... if I just pool the httpClientContexts to avoid using them concurrently ... since I am a midTier trusted source ... would pooling clientContexts be the right way to go?

Comment: All you need to do is to keep the same HttpContext instance for the same logical session (for instance by storing it as an attribute of HttpSession if your code is a webapp). In your particular case if you do not have to maintain different user identities represented by a SSL private key I would simply disable connection state tracking altogether.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  I saw some comment that seemed to discourage disabling state tracking.  So I did pretty much what you suggested ... kept a ref to the HttpClientContext in the session and when the session ends, put that HttpClientContext back into a pool.  It definitely resolved the constant handshaking issue.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

OK, while I'm not exactly an expert at reading the ssl trace, I do believe I have resolved it. I am on a thread but that is controlled by the server. I now pass the HttpSession in and keep a reference to the HttpClientConnection that I now create for each session.  I pool these HttpClientConnection objects (rudimentary pooling, basically just get/release).  So all calls w/in an http session use the same HttpClientContext.  Now it appears that I am NOT handShaking all the time.  There may have been a better way to do it, but this does indeed work, I have a few gremlins to look into (socket timeouts in < 1 millisecond?) ... but I'm confident that I'm non longer handShaking with each request (only each time I end up creating a new context) ... so this is all good.  Thanks,